# Escape Path in Bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, path

I need to escape and write the current directory folder path in .Bat file. Below is the code I use.

```
@echo off
echo %CD% > path.txt
echo Done!
```

It outputs below path:

```
C:\Users\Polo\Desktop\New folder
```

I need to write it escaped as below:

```
C:\\Users\\Polo\\Desktop\\New folder
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend replacing `\` with `\\`:

```
@echo off
echo %CD:\=\\% > path.txt
echo Done!
```

I found this (and plenty of other ways of manipulating strings in batch files) here: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Comment: thanks. it is a way but I prefer to run the batch file once. I know it can be done by setting variables in bat files but I do not have that knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I found a better way and have edited my answer.

Comment: So much better than the older one huge script.
i found the opposite way. Escapping whole chars from a ECHO line instead one to one, but is not :(

Comment: In one case I had to escape backslashes for sed to get 4 for every 1 in the path:  %PROJECT_DIR:\=\\\\%   Worked like a charm.  I didn't know batch had variable substitution like bash, very nice answer.